# Interface builder does not see my custom view controller inside a namespace?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder

I created a custom view controller like this:

```
class Form {
    class ContainerViewController : UIViewController {

        //...
    }
}
```

It compiles good, but interface builder seems not to see/find my controller when I set its class name.

I have tried some names but it didn't work. It this possible?

- `Form.ContainerViewController`
- `ContainerViewController`

[image: bad xcode]

Comment: Looks like not possible in Xcode, but you can do it programmatically.

Comment: Afaik it is not possible to set the class name of my controller programatically. I would need to create the entire view controller programatically

Comment: I just reported it. rdar://19918031

Comment: I see, do you have to use nested classes?

Comment: It is not a must for my case but being able to do this will be much better for class/object design purposes :)

Comment: Recently I got an email from Apple saying it was a `Duplicate of 18753511 (Open)`